# Emacs org mode: How to use "or" in org-agenda-custom-command

Tags: org-agenda

I have tried to code my `org-agenda-custom-commands` to show only todo's which are either priority `A` or priority `B`. However, I am only able to do this indirectly, by filtering out todo's that are NOT priority `C`. Why doesn't the or-function `|` in my code below work the way I want? (alternative 2 and 3).

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
  ("d" "Daily "(
    (tags-todo "+TODO=\"TODO\" -PRIORITY=\"C\" "  ( ; works
    (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-down))
    ))
  (tags-todo "+TODO=\"TODO\" +PRIORITY={\"B\"|\"A\"} "  ( ; works NOT
    (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-down))
    ))
  (tags-todo "+TODO=\"TODo\"  {+PRIORITY=\"B\"}|{+PRIORITY=\"A\"} "  ( ; works NOT
    (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-down))
    ))
  ))
))
```

Alternative 2 and 3 using the or-function `|` results in showing `A`, `B` and `C`, not only priority `A` and `B`, as was my intention.

What is wrong with my usage of the "|" function? How can I use `|` to show both priority `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contents of `{}` in an agenda command are regular expressions.  So something like `PRIORITY={\"B\"|\"A\"}` will only match if `PRIORITY` is `"A"` or `"B"`, including the quotes.  You also need more escaping in you regex (`\\|` instead of `|`).  A regex won't work if you don't pay the slash tax.

The correct search is `+PRIORITY={A\\|B}`.  You can also simplify things a little by using the `/` syntax.  Anything following a `/` is assumed to be a `TODO` keyword.  So `+PRIORITY={A\\|B}/TODO` will find all entries with keyword `TODO` and priority `A` or `B`.